# Insert first 3 elements of 2D array into MySql Database

Tags: python, mysql, append, pymysql

I have a list with data such as

```
infoarray[['1.', 'Name1', 'details1, '...', '...', '....'], ['2.', 'Name2, 'details2', '...', '...', '...'], ['3.', 'Name3', 'details3', '...', '...', '...']...]
```

I simply want to add the first 3 entries into a database table with the format

```
[PLACE],[NAME],[DETAILS]
```

Should be relatively simple. The data is already sorted, I would just simply have to append the first 3 elements of each inner array into my database. I tried the following code but I am getting an error.

```
//using pymysql

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        myTable
        (place, name, details)
    VALUES
        (%s, %s, %s)
""", infoarray)
db.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The error is "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
which is assume means that my formatting is wrong. I am relatively new to python, so I am very familiar with the nuances of using pymysql.

Comment: Don't know if your array example is exactly as in your code, but in the example there are 5 elements per item, while on the `insert` there are only 3

Comment: Oops, wasn't too clear, there is additional data in the array, but I only want to add the first 3 items to my database. Everything else is not needed in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are formatting 3 values in your query, but passing more than 3 elements per arra yitem.

Try changing your `executemany` call to:

```
cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        myTable
        (place, name, details)
    VALUES
        (%s, %s, %s)
""", [a[:3] for a in infoarray])
```

This way you will get only the first 3 elements in each array item and pass it to `executemany`

Comment: Issue solved! I assumed Python would automatically cut off the rest of the array since I am only using three elements. That was not the case. As a side note, I had a hard time debugging my execute command because without a proper conn.commit(), the execute statements did not stick to the database.